# I get this error "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead "

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

use this code and I get this error

> "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead"

When I want to use it with parameters of an excel table. If someone can help me, I thank you in advance.

I use all those libraries and functions for the rest of the work.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures 
    def R_Lineal1(x,y):
      lin = LinearRegression()
      lin.fit(x, y)
      plt.scatter(x, y, color = 'blue') 
      plt.plot(x, lin.predict(x), color = 'red')
      plt.title('Regresión Lineal, PWV v/s Módulo de Elasticidad')
      plt.xlabel('PWV [m/s]') 
      plt.ylabel('ME [MPa]') 
      plt.grid()
      plt.show() 
R_Lineal1(PWV_C,ME_C)
```

Comment: `R_Lineal1(PWV_C,ME_C)`

the end of my code

Comment: what are PWV_C,ME_C?

Comment: They are columns of numbers taken from an excel

Answer (score 1):

The most common error in my experience: The SK Learn only accepts 2D arrays for the x input. Use reshape

```
    x_train = x.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)
```

I think it does this for multiple regression as it could multiple inputs.

Comment: when adding what you said, I get this new error "Data must be 1-dimensional"

Comment: Where did you add it?

Comment: @gotenks IMHO `x = x.reshape(-1, 1)` is simpler.

Comment: That is simpler, ty

Comment: using that, I get this error "'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'"

Comment: Make the series into a np array, x_train = x.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)

Comment: The problem is solved, thank you very much

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

add it in def

```
def R_Lineal1(x,y):
  x = np.reshape(x, (len(x), 1))
  lin = LinearRegression()
  lin.fit(x, y)
  plt.scatter(x, y, color = 'blue') 
  plt.plot(x, lin.predict(x), color = 'red')
  plt.title('Regresión Lineal, PWV v/s Módulo de Elasticidad')
  plt.xlabel('PWV [m/s]') 
  plt.ylabel('ME [MPa]') 
  plt.grid()
  plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures 
    def R_Lineal1(x,y):

      x_train_new = x.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1) #update

      lin = LinearRegression()
      lin.fit(x, y)
      plt.scatter(x, y, color = 'blue') 
      plt.plot(x, lin.predict(x), color = 'red')
      plt.title('Regresión Lineal, PWV v/s Módulo de Elasticidad')
      plt.xlabel('PWV [m/s]') 
      plt.ylabel('ME [MPa]') 
      plt.grid()
      plt.show() 
R_Lineal1(PWV_C,ME_C)
```

Comment: @Pipe If my answer, or that of other users, was the solution to your question, please accept the answer as Stackoverflow Help Center rules, thank you